# C++ CMake build error: undefined reference to `boost::throw_exception(std::exception const&)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have been trying to integrate boost.Log into my project, but when building I am receiving the error message:

```
/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_date_time.so: undefined reference to `boost::throw_exception(std::exception const&)'
```

I have checked the ensure I do not have BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS defined anywhere, but am still stumped as to why I am getting this error. My CMAKE file is as follows:

```
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/lib/cross/boost/include)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib)
find_package(Boost 1.63.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem log REQUIRED)

message(status "** Boost Include: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(status "** Boost Libraries: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
message(status "** Boost Libraries: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

set (PROJECT_LINK_LIBS thrift crypto ssl sqlcipher)

link_directories( $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
                ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

include_directories( $ENV{LD_INCLUDE_PATH}
$ENV{LD_INCLUDE_PATH}/sqlcipher
${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

add_executable(databaseManager ${MY_SRC})

target_link_libraries(databaseManager ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS} )
```

The output from the FIND for the libraries seem to be ok:

```
-- Boost version: 1.63.0
1> -- Found the following Boost libraries:
1> --   system
1> --   filesystem
1> --   log
1> --   date_time
1> --   log_setup
1> --   thread
1> --   regex
1> --   chrono
1> --   atomic
1> status** Boost Include: /usr/lib/cross/boost/include
1> status** Boost Libraries: /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib
1> status** Boost Libraries:
/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_log.so;/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_log_setup.so;/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_regex.so;/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_atomic.so
```

Finally, the verbose output of the linking step where it fails:

```
/home/imx7/build/imx7-firmware-dev-package/src/maketools/obj.iMX7/bin/arm-devolo-linux-g++  -fexceptions -frtti -pthread -O3 -DNDEBUG  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/DatabaseManagerEventHandler.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/DatabaseManagerHandler.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/DatabaseManagerServer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/DatabaseManagerService.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/Logger.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/dbConnection.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_common/base_constants.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_common/base_types.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_dbManager/DatabaseManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_dbManager/dbManager_constants.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_dbManager/dbManager_types.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_supervisor/Info.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_supervisor/Supervision.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_supervisor/supervision_constants.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_supervisor/supervision_types.cpp.o  -o databaseManager  -L/usr/lib/cross/official_libs  -L/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/cross/official_libs:/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib: /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_system.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_filesystem.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_chrono.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_log.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_date_time.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_log_setup.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_thread.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_regex.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_atomic.so -lthrift -lcrypto -lssl -lsqlcipher 
/home/imx7/build/imx7-firmware-dev-package/src/maketools/binaries.iMX7/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-devolo-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-devolo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libz.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/cross/official_libs/libsqlcipher.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_date_time.so: undefined reference to `boost::throw_exception(std::exception const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/build.make:470: recipe for target 'src/databaseManager' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory '/var/cppbuild/DatabaseManager/build/Linux-Release'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:88: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/all' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/cppbuild/DatabaseManager/build/Linux-Release'
make[2]: *** [src/databaseManager] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:132: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone have any idea what else I can check or do to get past this error?

Cheers!

******* EDIT *********

There have been a few suggestions about adding exception to the COMPONENTS list. I have tried and tested this and unfortunately receive the same error.

The only thing of note is all the main libraries are linked dynamically (.so versions pulled in) and boost_exception is pulled in statically (.a version).

New version of find_package command:

```
find_package(Boost 1.63.0 COMPONENTS system atomic filesystem log exception REQUIRED)
```

Build error with above change:

```
/home/imx7/build/imx7-firmware-dev-package/src/maketools/obj.iMX7/bin/arm-devolo-linux-g++  -fexceptions -frtti -pthread -g  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/DatabaseManagerEventHandler.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/DatabaseManagerHandler.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/DatabaseManagerServer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/DatabaseManagerService.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/Logger.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/dbConnection.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_common/base_constants.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_common/base_types.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_dbManager/DatabaseManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_dbManager/dbManager_constants.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_dbManager/dbManager_types.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_supervisor/Info.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_supervisor/Supervision.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_supervisor/supervision_constants.cpp.o CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/thrift_supervisor/supervision_types.cpp.o  -o databaseManager  -L/usr/lib/cross/official_libs  -L/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/cross/official_libs:/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib: /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_system.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_atomic.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_filesystem.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_log.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_exception.a /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_date_time.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_log_setup.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_thread.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_regex.so /usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_chrono.so -lthrift -lcrypto -lssl -lsqlcipher 
/home/imx7/build/imx7-firmware-dev-package/src/maketools/binaries.iMX7/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-devolo-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-devolo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libz.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/cross/official_libs/libsqlcipher.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/cross/boost/lib/libboost_date_time.so: undefined reference to `boost::throw_exception(std::exception const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/build.make:471: recipe for target 'src/databaseManager' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory '/var/cppbuild/DatabaseManager/build/Linux-Debug'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:88: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/all' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/cppbuild/DatabaseManager/build/Linux-Debug'
make[2]: *** [src/databaseManager] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/databaseManager.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:132: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: This way to write cmake file is really odd! Try to use modern CMake... I suggest you this link: https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/ https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1 (the sources are very useful) and on Windows `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` allow you to specify where you are installing all your libraries. For example, I built `cpprestsdk`, `OpenCV` and `Boost C++` and installed in my location... Now I don't have to borrow with link options or include options.

Comment: Thanks for the links regarding cleaning up my cmake, will definitely take those on board once I get past this error :)

Comment: I noticed in your `message()` output that `Boost_LIBRARIES` is emtpy. Could this be a case of ["_Boost_LIBRARIES not defined_"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56036266/11107541)?

Answer (score 6):

An update if anyone else ever comes across this.

The only way I was able to get it to work was with having the following snippet of code:

```
#define BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS
#include <boost/throw_exception.hpp>
void boost::throw_exception(std::exception const & e){
//do nothing
}
```

I played with the ordering of the libraries, with including them all explicitly, with using findBoost.cmake and all to no avail. Just a random quirk I guess!

Comment: Actually its document that void boost::throw_exception(std::exception const & e); is a user defined function not one from boost  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/exception/doc/throw_exception.html. Passing -fexceptions to compiler will also resolve this by forcing the compiler to generate exception handling code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when updating from boost 1.82 to 1.84. Suddenly I got the same unresolved external symbol errors.

I had to explicitly enable exception handling for some targets.
I did this by adding:

`add_compile_options(/EHsc)`