# Boost_LIBRARIES not defined

Tags: boost, cmake

I am trying to compile FreeLing, that uses CMake to detect Boost. This is the code responsible for it:

```
  find_package(Boost COMPONENTS regex filesystem thread program_options REQUIRED)
```

These components are found (accordingly to the output generated by CMake):

```
-- Found Boost 1.70.0 at /home/ambs/usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS regex;filesystem;thread;program_options
-- Found boost_headers 1.70.0 at /home/ambs/usr/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.70.0
-- Found boost_regex 1.70.0 at /home/ambs/usr/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.70.0
--   libboost_regex.so.1.70.0
-- Adding boost_regex dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_filesystem 1.70.0 at /home/ambs/usr/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.70.0
--   libboost_filesystem.so.1.70.0
-- Adding boost_filesystem dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_thread 1.70.0 at /home/ambs/usr/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.70.0
--   libboost_thread.so.1.70.0
-- Adding boost_thread dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_program_options 1.70.0 at /home/ambs/usr/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.70.0
--   libboost_program_options.so.1.70.0
-- Adding boost_program_options dependencies: headers
-- Boost  found.
-- Found Boost components:
   regex;filesystem;thread;program_options
```

Nevertheless, it looks like `Boost_LIBRARIES` is never set. I tried this:

```
  find_package(Boost COMPONENTS regex filesystem thread program_options REQUIRED)
  message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES=" ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

and it output always a empty string.

For reference, I have CMake version 3.14.3, and Boost version 1.70.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The line

> Found Boost 1.70.0 at /home/ambs/usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0

means that CMake module [FindBoost.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FindBoost.html) doesn't detects Boost libraries and headers using its own methods but resorts to `BoostConfig.cmake` script, located in the directory shown in the log.

Documentation for `FindBoost.cmake` module notes such way:

> This module finds headers and requested component libraries OR a CMake
>   package configuration file provided by a “Boost CMake” build. For the
>   latter case skip to the “Boost CMake” section below. For the former
>   case results are reported in variables:

In short, using `BoostConfig.cmake` script means that it sets its own variables or targets, and ones described in the documentation for `FindBoost.cmake` are not valid.

Most likely, the "Config" file sets **IMPORTED targets** in the same manner, as described in `FindBoost.cmake` documentation, that is `Boost::regex`, `Boost::filesystem` and so on.

---

If you want to disable using `BoostConfig.cmake` and force `FindBoost.cmake` to behave as described in its documentation, set `Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE` variable. E.g., when call `cmake`:

```
cmake -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=ON <other-options>
```

Comment: I can't upvote your answer more than once, unfortunately. Thank you very much. You have no idea the number of hours I lost yesterday.