# How do I stop project with boost dependency finding the wrong ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} location, when building in Visual Studio 2019 with CMake

Tags: boost, cmake, visual-studio-2019, google-fruit

I am attempting to build the fruit library - https://github.com/google/fruit, in Visual Studio 2019

When I ran the install step for the first time it was unable to find <boost\unordered_map.hpp>

After a quick google, I set BOOST_ROOT as C:\ExtBuildUtils\Boost, which it ignored until I put cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21) at the top of the file and then I saw the following output in the Configure step

```
1> [CMake] -- Found Boost: C:/ExtBuildUtils/Boost/boost_1_75_0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.75.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.75.0")
```

However again when I attempted to install the library it couldn't find <boost\unordered_map.hpp>

I could see that the compiler invocation said `-IC:\ExtBuildUtils\Boost`, which didn't look right

So I added a message to CMakeLists.txt

```
message(STATUS "Boost include dirs: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

Which outputs

```
1> [CMake] -- Boost include dirs: C:/ExtBuildUtils/Boost
```

OK, so maybe I need to set BOOST_ROOT as C:\ExtBuildUtils\Boost\boost_1_75_0

I made the above modification but it still outputs the exact same location.

How do I stop project with boost dependency finding the wrong ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} location?

Comment: The line started with `Found Boost` means that CMake finds configuration file for Boost. This file doesn't define variables like `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS`, see [that my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56036743/3440745). So the first thing you need to decide for yourself: whether do you want to use such variable (so the config file is not an option for you) or do you want to use imported targets (which are provided both by config file and by CMake itself).

Comment: What is the point of this configuration file, I don't get what it does

Comment: You may read CMake documentation about differences between config files and module files when use `find_package`. See e.g. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html or https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html.